# Vuetify design is broken when deployed on Heroku

Tags: css, vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

## Assumption

I am building a service with `docker` and `Nuxt.js.`. I am using `Vuetyify` for the user interface, but when deployed to `Heroku`, the `CSS` design is broken. Specifically, the alert width is not applied, there are blank spaces in the alert area, and other strange behavior. It works fine in the development environment. I have looked into it, but all I found is that the `CSS` loads differently in the development environment than in the production environment.
Is there any solution to this problem?

## What we want to solve

I want to solve `Vuetify` design collapse on `Heroku`.

## Code

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "export": "nuxt export",
    "serve": "nuxt serve",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.6",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "jest": "^27.4.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0"
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    APP_NAME: process.env.APP_NAME,
    BOOK_URL: process.env.BOOK_URL,
    AXIOS_POST: process.env.AXIOS_POST
  },

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'KOUDOKU',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'ja'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
・
・
・

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
    '@nuxtjs/eslint-module',
    // Doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/vuetify
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],

  moment: {
    locales: ['ja']
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth'
  ],

  // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
・
・
・
 // Added for anti-styling
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extractCSS: true,
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          styles: {
            name: 'styles',
            test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            chunks: 'initial',
            enforce: true
          },
          components: {
            name: 'components',
            test: /app\/components/,
            chunks: 'all',
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

  router: {
    middleware: ['auth']
  }
}
```

heroku.yml

```
setup:
  config:
    NODE_ENV: production
    NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION: false
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
  config:
    WORKDIR: app
    API_URL: "https://book-app-api-v1.herokuapp.com"
run:
  web: yarn run start
```

Comment: How does it look if you build it locally? Also, what if you comment out your custom `optimization` configuration in `nuxt.config.js`?

Comment: @kissu  Local is not a problem. Also, the customization mentioned in ``nuxt.config.js`` build was added because the layout was broken on ``Heroku.``

Comment: It's still broken right now no? Why was it added initially?

Comment: @kissu Sorry, I think I misled you with my question text. The ``CSS`` layout was broken, so I added a customization to the ``build`` field based on information I found on the net.

Comment: You should probably keep the default configuration and try to find where is the issue exactly. Do you have the HTML and CSS of the non-working code in production? What's the difference between the 2 in the devtools?